# Convert image to byte for iphone application using xamarin forms

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin.forms

I want to convert an image to bytes for server upload. So, I have used the below code which is throwing error. Can anyone please help me out?

> Error:  “Reference to type ‘system.componentmodel.typeconverter’ 
>   claims it is defined assembly system but it could not be found".

```
public static byte[] imgToByteConverter(System.Drawing.Image inImg)
{
    ImageConverter imgCon = new ImageConverter();   
    return (byte[])imgCon.ConvertTo(inImg, typeof(byte[]));        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Xamarin Form Image is not the same as a System.Drawing.Image.  System.Drawing.Image is a W32 class and does not exist in Xamarin.  You can't convert a XF image to a byte[].  Instead, you need to refer to whatever resource (file, stream, url, etc) was used to create the Image and use that to create the byte[].

Comment: It is the image captured from iphone camera. So, What is the best way to convert?